# Sql with empty string, same eligibility, different results

Tags: sql, oracle

I've read many things around how Oracle handles null or empty string.

Let's say I have a table with these datas :

| id | myfield |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | mydata1 |
| id2 | mydata2 |

```
select * from mytable where myfield <> ' ';
select * from mytable where myfield is not null;
select * from mytable where myfield <> '' ;
```

When executing the first two query, I get some results. Why not with the third one ?, knowing that : it's a NOT clause, and even though my empty string was reinterpreted as null, it would make it as a *is not null clause* (making the 2nd and third quite the same), making it eligible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle is weird in terms of handling nulls. It was designed, developed, and tested in the 70s, well before the SQL Standard was officially established. Oracle is a great engine but it has quirks; this is one of them.

The expression:

```
where myfield <> ''
```

gets automatically rephrased by the Oracle engine as:

```
where myfield <> null
```

And, since no value can satisfy this predicate, no rows are returned.

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60f98934dc88825468d30b4b0fcdfce2).